# Kubernetes Minio tenant ui redirects to 0.0.0.0:9443

Tags: kubernetes, operators, minio

i've setup a minio tenant using the [minio operator](https://github.com/minio/operator) and was following the getting started guide.
Now if i create an IngressRoute to for the ui i'm just getting redirected to 0.0.0.0:9443.

This is the IngressRoute:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: minio-console-ui-http
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`minio-console.mysecretdomain.tld`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: minio-cluster-console
          port: 9090
```

do i miss a config parameter for the console?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue but I figured it out.

You need to add this ENV var to your minio tenant, then remove the deployment (it will be added again)

```
env:
- name: CONSOLE_SECURE_TLS_REDIRECT
  value: "false"
```